# How to prove this property about a measurable function f

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra in $X$ and $f:X \to \mathbb{R}^N$ a measurable function. Prove that $G\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ open $\implies f^{-1}(G) \in\mathcal{A}$.

My attempet: If we write $f(x)=(f_1(x),\dots, f_N(x))$ where $f_i:X \to \mathbb{R}$, we have that
$$ f_i=P_i \circ f$$ where $P_i:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ is the projection of the $i$-coordinate. Since $P_i$ is continuous and an open map it's true that $P_i(G)=A \subset \mathbb{R}$ open and then follows that
$$f_i^{-1}(A)=f^{-1}(P^{-1}_i(A))). $$
By the description of the open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ we can write $A$ as an disjoint countable union of open intervals and maybe with some work we can prove by this that $f^{-1}_i(A) \in \mathcal{A}$. The real problem here is that it's not true that $P^{-1}_i(A)=G$. There is a way to make this argument work?

Comment: I am not sure what is your definition of measurable function. But to my knowledge the definition is that given two measurable spaces $X$, $Y$, the map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is measurable if $f^{-1}(U)$ is measurable in $X$ for every measurable set $U$ in $Y$.

In your case if $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is equipped with Lebesgue measure, then any open set is measurable. Then the conclusion follows directly. I may be missing something here...

You should not assume that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: That is another doubt that I have, the exercise do not tell if $\mathbb{R}^N$ is equiped with the Lebesgue measure, so I don't know if I can suppose that. The definition that i'm using is the following: $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable if for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$ follows that $f^{-1}((a,+\infty)) \in \mathcal{A}$ and a function from  $X$ to $\mathbb{R}^N$ is measurable if every coordinate function is. In fact, $f_i$ is not continuous, but the projection is, my mistake while typing.

Comment: To prove that each component $f_i \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable implies $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}^N$ is measurable, use the fact that every open set in $\mathbb{R}^N$ is a countable union of "rectangles".

Comment: Then in this case it is quite pointless to talk about measurable functions if you do not specify the sigma algebra of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. I can equip $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with the worst kind of sigma algebra $\{\mathbb{R}^{n},\emptyset\}$ which does not contain a certain fixed non-empty open set $U\subsetneq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and the question does not make any sense. 

Based on your definition of measurable function, it is highly possible that $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is equipped with the usual Lebesgue sigma algebra. It is best to verify your textbook to see if such assumption is made.

Comment: The definition used is precisely the one that I wrote in the above comment :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any open set $G$ in $\mathbb R^{n}$ is a union of sets of the type $(a_1,b_1)\times (a_2,b_2)\times \cdots \times (a_n,b_n)$ with $a_i, b_i \in \mathbb Q$ for each $i$. Since $f_i^{-1}(a_i,b_i) \in \mathcal A$ for each $i$ it follows that $f^{-1}(G) \in  \mathcal A$.